# Can't we just take RAM memory dump of object to be serialized?

Tags: java, memory, serialization

When we have to save an object in persistent storage or transfer across network, we serialize the object (In this case, the object should implement serializable interface). My question is why there is the restriction that the object class should implement serializable interface. Can't we serialize any random object by taking its memory dump as it is.

Comment: A major principle of object oriented design is that a programmer should not have to worry about the internal implementation of objects.  Java serialization allows a Java 8 runtime to deserialize a String serialized by a Java 16 runtime.  That would not be possible if serialization were just a memory dump, as the internal implementation has changed.

Comment: Dumping from RAM and having an interface are not mutually exclusive. The serializable interface is just a flag that denotes that it makes sense to serialize something. It does no more than that. For the sake of argument, what you are proposing *could* be the actual implementation of how objects are serialized, but it is exactly that: an implementation detail. Regardless of how serialization is achieved, having a flag which specifies whether or not something is suitable for serialization is useful, because it stops you trying to serialize things which it does not make sense to serialize.

Comment: @Michael : Yes, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Well it could *in theory*.  But RAM dumping wouldn't work for any current JVM ... or any alternative practical JVM implementation approach (that I can think of).  I have listed some of the problems that would arise if you tried it with a typical HotSpot JVM.

Comment: Pointers or Java references would not work in a JVM dump.

Comment: Yea ... so you would need a JVM where references were represented as (say) PIDLAM indexes.  (Clearly not compatible with HotSpot, but I've seen an ancient experimental JVM where they did this.)  There are conceptually harder parts to the problem than references :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why there is the restriction that the object class should implement serializable interface.

Because certain kinds of object are fundamentally not serializable in a HotSpot JVM.  Instances of classes like `Thread`, `Process`, `Socket`, and `Class`.  (In some cases, serialization is conceivable but not practical.  For others, it is inconceivable because the objects' behavior depends on state that is not accessible to Java.)

> Can't we serialize any random object by taking its memory dump as it is.

A few of reasons spring to mind (assuming that we are talking on a JVM based on HotSpot).

1. Instances of the above classes could not be properly serialized that way.
2. If you copy a memory snapshot, it has to be copied to the same address in the destination address space.  Otherwise the pointers will be broken.
3. Each object has an object header which includes a special reference to the object's class.  The references are liable to be different.
4. To take copy a block of memory containing objects, you would need to disable the GC at both the sending and receiving end, and also all other application threads.  It would be a stop the world event ... at both ends.
5. The objects that you want to copy are *unlikely* to be allocated in the same block of memory.

Some of the above could be addressed with a radically different JVM architecture, but there some deeper problems as well.  (Plus this approach could only ever work between "like" JVM implementations.)

It is just not practical as an implementation approach for serializing / deserializing Java objects.