# Why can't I store un-serialized data structure on disk the same way I can store them in memory?

Tags: serialization, memory-management, disk

Firstly, I am assuming that data structures, like a hash-map for example, can only be stored in-memory but not on disk unless they are serialized. I want to understand why not?

What is holding us back from dumping a block of memory which stores the data structure directly into disk without any modifications?

Something like a JSON could be thought of as a "serialized" python dictionary. We can very well store JSON in files, so why not a dict?

You may say how would you represent non-string values like bool/objects on disk? I can argue "the same way you store them in memory". Am I missing something here?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968101/cant-we-just-take-ram-memory-dump-of-object-to-be-serialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

naming a few problems:

1. Big endian vs Little endian makes reading data from disk depend on the architecture of the CPU, so if you just dumped it you won't be able to read it again on different device.
2. items are not contagious in memory, a list (or dictionary) for example only contains pointers to things that exist "somewhere" in memory, you can only dump contagious memory, otherwise you are only storing the locations in memory that the data was in, which won't be the same when you load the program again.
3. the way structures are laid in memory can change between two compiled versions of the same program, so if you just recompile your application, you may get different layouts for structures in memory so you just lost your data.
4. different versions of the same application may wish to update the shape of the structures to allow extra functionality, this won't be possible if the data shape on disk is the same as in memory. (which is one of the reasons why you shouldn't be using pickle for portable data storage, despite it using a memory serializer)